# How to read/write the public key in an RSA structure

Tags: c, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption, pem

Using C, I can generate and write an RSA public key to a PEM file using `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey()`,

But I want to write multiple public keys to a single file (like known_hosts or authorized_hosts), rather than have a `separate PEM file for each`.

I know how to `encode/decode base64`,

But how do I get the `public key from the RSA structure (which I can base64 encode) and later read the same key from file and put it back into the RSA structure for encrypting/decrypting`?

Comment: If you can able to write single key into file.Then you can do that repeatedly. and authorized_hosts file consists single key or multiple keys with the prefix of the key type for ex:` ``ssh-rsa`` `Key`and the file can consists multiple keys.Known_hosts is separate file which consists hosts which are accepted to access through ssh.Both files are quit different.If you can able to show how you are writing single key, so that we can guide you to make it for multiple keys.

Comment: Why not just combine the output of that call into one file? PEM is just text and each key is distinguished by BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE notation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the reply, perhaps I'm making the question more complicated than it needs to be. I want to know how to create a text string representing the public key from an RSA structure. Then I want to also convert that text string back into the public key portion of the RSA structure. I can base64 encode/decode and read/write a text file, I just don't know how to get the public key in and out of the RSA struct.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `PEM_read_RSAPublicKey()`?

Comment: What happens if you try to write 2 public keys to the same file with `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey()`?

Answer (score 0):

PEM_write_RSAPublicKey() will append to the file if opened with "a+" but there is no indication of which keys are for which client. I don't want PEM formatting, only to write each public key to a single line in the file.

I found that the public key is in DER format, which I can get from the RSA struct using:

```
len = i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsap, 0);
buf1 = buf2 = (unsigned char *)malloc(len + 1);
rc = i2d_RSAPublicKey(rsap, (unsigned char **)&buf2);
```

Then I base64-encode buf1 and write it to my file. 
After reading it from file, putting it back into the RSA struct is just the reverse:

```
rsap = d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, (const unsigned char **)&buf1, (long)len);
```

Comment: Curious, how does this approach tell you which keys are for which client if all of them go to the same file?

Comment: I put the client info on the same line as the key, like the lnown_hosts file. The whole point was to be able to write whatever I want instead of a PEM format that requires a different file for each client.